# Javascript using return with multiple functions

Tags: javascript, function, return

```
function mainFunc(mainParameter) {
 return {
  subFunc1 : function (sub1Parameter) {
   return sub1Parameter;
  },
  subFunc2 : function (sub2Parameter) {
   return sub2Parameter
  }
 }
}

// This works
console.log(mainFunc().subFunc1('example text'));

// I need this
console.log(mainFunc('example text'));
```

How can i use 'return' with mainFunc() like last line in the code block.

Comment: How would you decide between using subFunc1 or subFunc2?

Comment: [^^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75833803/javascript-using-return-with-multiple-functions#comment133765559_75833803) or doing something else entirely??

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `if` to see if `mainFunc` was called with any arguments, then if `mainFunc` was called with an argument, have it do whatever it is it's supposed to do with that parameter instead of returning the object, like this:

```js
function mainFunc(...args) {
    if (args.length !== 0) {
        // Do whatever it's supposed to do when it gets an argument
        console.log("(Got an argument)");
        return args[0];
    }
    // Didn't get any arguments
    console.log("(Didn't get any arguments)");
    return {
        subFunc1: function (sub1Parameter) {
            return sub1Parameter;
        },
        subFunc2: function (sub2Parameter) {
            return sub2Parameter;
        },
    };
}

console.log(mainFunc().subFunc1("example text"));

console.log(mainFunc("example text"));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need only the second type of output `console.log(mainFunc('example text'));` you can do this way:

```
function mainFunc(mainParameter) {

 return {

  subFunc1 : function (sub1Parameter) {
      return sub1Parameter;
  }(mainParameter),

  subFunc2 : function (sub2Parameter) {
      return sub2Parameter
  }(mainParameter)

 }

}
```

Otherwise this one works in both cases:

```
function mainFunc(mainParameter) {

    const subFunc1 = function (sub1Parameter) {
        return sub1Parameter;
    };

    const subFunc2 = function (sub2Parameter) {
        return sub2Parameter;
    };

    if (mainParameter)
        return {subFunc1: subFunc1(mainParameter), subFunc2: subFunc2(mainParameter)}; 
 
    return {subFunc1: subFunc1, subFunc2: subFunc2}; 
}
```